# How to load chrome's default profile when using Chrome Cef browser

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am new to c# browser based on Chromium; the browser itself works but what I am wanting is for the browser to not start in Incognito mode every time a user launches the browser. I have attempted to try to people's suggestions in older forums about this but I was not successful. This software will be used on many PCs and in order to best achieve this; it needs to use the environment property. Can someone please help me get this achieved and teach me? Here is my current running code:

```
namespace NGH
{
    public partial class facebookbrowser : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public facebookbrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
    }

    private void facebookbrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }


    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("apps.facebook.com/warcommander");
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void facebookbrowser_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
        Application.Exit(); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Loading default Chrome profile, don't do it, it's not allowed. Chrome browser and your browser will conflict and loose user data.

Comment: @273K okay than, how can I create a profile to save cache so that they won't have to sign in every single time the browser is launched.

Comment: Can't believe you are banned by Google and can't search "cefsharp user profile".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading of `Chrome's default profile` is not supported.

Additionally `Chromium` only allows a single process to access a `cache(profile)`. If `Chrome` was open then you'd be unable to have your process (application) access the cache.

In `CefSharp` the default is to use an `In Memory` cache. You can specify a `CachePath` to use a disk based cache.

```cs
var settings = new CefSettings()
{
    //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
    CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
};
```

See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cefsettings-and-browsersettings

Answer (score 0):

Use CefSettings.CachePath to set the Cachepath to any place you need
This is C# and VB.NET sample:

```
{
    var MySettings = new CefSettings();
    string TheCacheDirectory = YourBrowserSessionsUserDirectory + @"\cache";
    MySettings.UserDataPath = YourBrowserSessionsUserDirectory;
    if (IsPrivateBrowser == "true")
        MySettings.CachePath = "";
    else
        MySettings.CachePath = TheCacheDirectory;
}
```

In VB.NET use github: https://icsharpcode.github.io/CodeConverter/

```
Dim MySettings As New CefSettings()
Dim TheCacheDirectory As String = YourBrowserSessionsUserDirectory.ToString() & "\cache"
MySettings.UserDataPath = YourBrowserSessionsUserDirectory
If IsPrivateBrowser Is "true" Then
    MySettings.CachePath = ""
Else
    MySettings.CachePath = TheCacheDirectory
End If
```